# connecting to autobahn's WrappingWebSocketServerFactory with native javascript WebSocket

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, autobahn

i am using the WrappingWebSocketServerFactory to wrap around an existing protocol. i am attempting to use native javascript websockets to connect, but get this error from the server as a result:

406 this server only speaks ['binary', 'base64'] WebSocket subprotocols

do i have to use autobahn's js library to proceed or will native websockets work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was initializing the websocket like so:

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
```

i changed it to:

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080", ['binary']);
```

Comment: Yes, this is documented here https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/wrapping#websocket-transport-scheme